# Easy way to add a MIB?

Tags: snmp, mib

I want to add some tests to a block of remote servers. It looks pretty straightforward to code this using NetSNMP::Agent from Perl. What I'm not clear on is the best way to add the definitions to a (new or existing) MIB.

I've found a block that was assigned to our workplace but the contact name is long gone so I doubt anyone is maintaining it. Looking about for apps to create a new MIB seems to find lots of $500 apps.

If I want to add some db tests (record count, usage) to my SNMP block at .1.3.6.1.4.1.9892 is there a simple way? I read one article about using a UUID to (attempt to) insure uniqueness. Is this commonly done?

Or should I just stick with the numeric designation and make up something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt regarding your private OID and you just can't get a definitive answer regarding the usage of this namespace, you can always register a new one. But in practice, it is usually sufficient to just start a new subtree at a relatively high number, say '.1.3.6.1.4.1.9892.10000` and build your structure from there. While you are at it, make sure the data is documented and kept up to date so that other people 10 years down the road doesn't face the same issue.

Other than that, you don't need some expensive tools for a small group of data points, just use some other MIBs as template to create what you want.